# Angular: HTTP Get-Request is always responsing a 404 Error with the error message Collection 'joke' not found

Tags: angular, http

I just started learning Angular. Now I want to execute a HTTP Get-Request to get a joke from this joke api: https://witzapi.de/api-docs/.

The api endpoint to get a joke is https://witzapi.de/api/joke. If i call this endpoint via my browser i get always a joke in JSON. But if I want to get a joke with my current angular application I get always a 404 error with the message Collection 'joke' not found.

I don't know why I get this error message and how I can solve it. Have anyone an idea?

Here is the affected code:

```
export class JokeCollectionService {
  joke: String | undefined;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
     this.getJoke()
  }

  getJoke() {
    return this.http.get<any>('https://witzapi.de/api/joke').subscribe(data => {
      this.joke = data.text;
    });
  }
}
```

I already looked into angular's documentation and for tutorials and tried to fix it. But it haven't worked.

Comment: Isn't the issue the fact that the API returns an array of objects, and thus you should assign your variable with `this.joke = data[0].text;`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some query string parameters, e.g.

```
https://witzapi.de/api/joke/?limit=2&category=funny&language=en-gb
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason of the error message. I used the in memory web api. After removing this module it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).